# haml documentation - where is it?

Tags: haml, ruby-on-rails

I've just started with Rails (having previously worked in Django). The hardest part is working out how to use haml.

I have found the official [haml documentation](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html). However, there seems to be no coverage here of syntax - if/else clauses, for loops, etc.

Other than Googling for examples, is there any official documentation of syntax in haml? Or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HAML doesn't have if/else clauses or loops.  HAML allows you to execute any Ruby code that may include those clauses.

In the documentation you referenced, there's a section on `Running Ruby` which has examples of an `each` iterator and a `case` statement.  An `if` is handled in the same way.

Comment: `for i in array` syntax is also supported, and in most cases the `do` can be omitted.

Comment: Ah, I see! thanks - different from Django template languages.